# android - db.rawquery "order by" doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by

I want to order all my db entries using "ORDER BY" in my db table.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong, but it doesn't work.
Here my code:

```
class NoteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "note.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;


public NoteHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Notes (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, note TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    //no-op, since will not be called until 2nd schema
    //version exists
}

public void insert(String note) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("note", note);
    //you must pass it at lease one name of a colum
    getWritableDatabase().insert("Notes", "note", cv);
}

public void update(String id, String note){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args = {id};

    cv.put("note", note);
    getWritableDatabase().update("Notes", cv, "_id=?", args);
}

public void delete(String id){
    getWritableDatabase().delete("Notes", "_id=?", new String[] {id});
}

public Cursor getAll(){
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, note FROM Notes",  null));
}


public Cursor getAllSorted(){
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT note  FROM Notes  ORDER BY note  COLLATE NOCASE", null));

}

public String getNote(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(1));
}

public Cursor getById(String id) {
    String[] args = {id};

    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, note FROM Notes WHERE _id=?", args));
}

 }
```

If someone knows where is the problem help me, thanks.

Ok here is the main code:

```
NoteAdapter adapter = null;
NoteHelper helper = null;
Cursor dataset_cursor = null;
EditText editNote = null;
//this is how track which note we are working on
String noteId = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try{


    setContentView(R.layout.history);

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    editNote = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);


    helper = new NoteHelper(this);
    dataset_cursor = helper.getAll();
    startManagingCursor(dataset_cursor);
    adapter = new NoteAdapter(dataset_cursor);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
class NoteAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    NoteAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(Ztutorial11.this, c);


    }




    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
        NoteHolder holder = (NoteHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }

    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        NoteHolder holder = new NoteHolder(row);

        row.setTag(holder);
        return (row);
    }
}

static class NoteHolder {
    private TextView noteText = null;

    NoteHolder(View row){
        noteText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.note);


    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, NoteHelper helper) {
        noteText.setText(helper.getNote(c));
    }
}



   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
awesome.inflate(R.menu.menu_expresions, menu);
return true;

   }
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
switch(item.getItemId()){
case R.id.Az:

    //something to do
    helper.getAllSorted();
    //update the view
    dataset_cursor.requery();
    return true;
case R.id.Za:

    //something to do

    return true;
case R.id.deleteall:

    //something to do
    helper.deleteAll();
    dataset_cursor.requery();
    return true;
case R.id.undo:

    //something to do

    return true;

}

return false;
 }



 };
```

Comment: can you explain what "it doesn't work" mean? `getAllSorted()` will give you a sorted result if there is no crash preventing that.

Comment: I mean no crash, but nothing happend.

Comment: You get `null` as result from that method or you get a cursor with 0 rows or your app does not show anything? Can't help if you don't know what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: Simple in main activity when i click a button i pass: helper.getAllSorted(); I think this is correct and after prees it nothing happens and no crash.

Comment: You don't update the UI with the new data maybe? In case there is some `ListView` with a `CursorAdapter` change the cursor of that adapter to the new one you just got or replace the Adapter with a new one using the new cursor.

Comment: True i din't update the UI. So i should use: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

Comment: I put my main code. I updated the cursor and the = nothing happens :S

Comment: I just attempted to correct the indenting, and realized that as written, the code you gave us cannot compile.  Where is the missing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it that way:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Az:
            dataset_cursor = helper.getAllSorted();
            adapter.changeCursor(dataset_cursor);
            return true;
        case R.id.Za:
            // something to do
            return true;
        case R.id.deleteall:
            // something to do
            helper.deleteAll();
            dataset_cursor.requery();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case R.id.undo:
            // something to do
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

first you assign the new sorted result to `dataset_cursor` then tell the adapter, that the cursor has changed. The `deleteall` case will probably need the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` line I added there.

Comment: Well, and keep in mind, that cursor.requery() is deprecated right now)

Answer (score 2):

```
dataset_cursor = helper.getAll();
```

You're not using `getAllSorted()`...

Additionally, `onOptionsItemSelected()` isn't being called anywhere, and even if it was, the return value to the call to `getAllSorted()` isn't being used, either.

Comment: yes sorry i dint copy that but i have onOptionItemSelected sorry but = doesn't work :S

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, but here are some guesses/things to try.

1) There seems to be two spaces after note and before COLLATE. Not sure if that makes a difference. (In fact there seem to be extra spaces throughout several different locations of that SQL string)

2) What happens when you remove the COLLATE NOCASE clause? Just wondering if that's the issue, or if it's the actual ORDER BY clause that's failing.

3) Do you need to specify ASC/DESC after COLLATE NOCASE?

Comment: i did all but is = nothing happens and no crashes :S

Comment: Show us the code that calls this getAllSorted(). How do you know it isn't working? Are you mapping it to a UI? Printing it out in logs?